# Rails controller render json without encoding

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to send `json` data from my rails controller but it always converts `&` into unicode `\u0026`. Is it possible to tell rails controller not to convert `&` into unicode `\u0026` ?

Below is how my method looks like in controller (this is just dummy test method)

```
def send_detail
  render json: { data: "name?surname&otherdetail" } 
end
```

when I visit `localhost:3000/tests/send_detail` in postman, I get `{ "data":"name?surname\u0026otherdetail" }`

How can I tell `render` method not to convert `&` into unicode character `\u0026` ?. If possible I would like to preserve `&` only for this method rather than changing Rails config to not covert json data in unicode character for all rails application.

**UPDATE**

I am able to force rails not to covert `&` into unicode character by adding this line `ActiveSupport.escape_html_entities_in_json = false` but this changes the settings in all Rails application, which is not what I want. I only like to preserve `&` in one method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually convert it in the single action that you want it not to apply:

```
def send_detail
  render json: JSON.generate({ data: "name?surname&otherdetail" })
end
```